# How to convert GMST to GMST° (degrees) for calculating RA

Tags: the-moon, right-ascension, sidereal-period

For calculating the Right Ascension of the moon I need the GMST (Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time) in Degrees.
I have found the formula
GMST = 100.4606184 + 0.9856473662862 * D + H * 15,
D = number of days, H = Universal Time in hours
I think the unit of GMST is days.
RA is then calculated GMST(degrees) + Longitude(degrees) converted to Hours Minutes Seconds.
In the example to the above formula D = 305.209, H = 17, that results GMST(days?) = 656.288 but GMST(degrees) = 296.288° For the actual date the values are 8750.95 days? and it should be -11.54° for the actual RA.
How can I convert GMST(days) to GMST(degrees)?
Or do I think wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The formula you found **is** in degrees. You can tell this is the case via the $15*H$ term.

Comment: BTW, JPL have an equation for GMST [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html#greenwich-mean-sidereal-time). The result is in seconds, so divide by 240 to get degrees. Note that 3155760000 = 36525 * 86400, the number of seconds in a Julian century. I don't know why they include that term...

Comment: "RA is then calculated GMST(degrees) + Longitude(degrees)".  This is the equation for comuting local sidereal time, not RA.

Comment: You didn't mention which epoch your D is measured from. It looks like it's midnight at the start of 2000-Jan-1. The GMST at the [J2000 epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J2000) is ~280.46062°.

Comment: The first calc that gives and answer of 656.288 is in degrees. You need to subtract (or add) multiples of 360 to put the "time" in the proper range of 0 to 360. That gives GMST = 296.288 degrees. Not sure how you are doing the second calc that gives 8750.95 degrees which does not equal -11.54 degrees unless you have included the longitude but did not provide that value to us.